# AngularJS doesn't push new record into the array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, push

I create a new record, this record is successfully added to the database. That's good.
But the problem is that it doesn't update the list of existing records - means the `push` function doesn't seems to be working.

This is inside the controller:

```
$scope.posts = Posts.query();
...
$scope.saveForm = function(post) {
  var p = new Post(post);
  p.$save(function (response) {
  $scope.posts.push(angular.extend(p, response.id));
    console.log('saved');
    console.log(response.id);
  });
};
```

I've tried to use only `push()` without `angular.extend()`, also tried to add `$scope.posts = Posts.query();` in the end of the controller, but it didn't help - the new record is still not added to the current list of posts.

What might cause this? I've found similar topics here on SO, but it didn't help me to solve this issue.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I see in `console.log($scope.posts);` the new post, it just doesn't appear in the list of posts.

**EDIT2:**
I tried also `$scope.$apply();` after the `push` command, but it led to this error message:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

**EDIT3:**
I found out that when I try to delete a records, the list doesn't get updated as well (only after refresh).

**EDIT4:**
When I add a new record, in the JS is this output (the new record, properly saved, just not updated in the list where are all items):

```
Resource {id: Object, title: "hohohohooho", body: null, starred: null, created_at: "2015-10-27T04:00:06.943Z"…}
```

`ID` is accessible as `response.id.$oid`.

Comment: shouldn't the extend be `angular.extend(p,{id: response.id})` ?

Comment: you need to provide more code. Angular uses standard js array push and it works quite well.

Comment: before pushing o extended of p into posts , log to see what the p is printed

Comment: @charlietfl - thanks, I tried this option, but unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: @MohammadJavad Seyyedi - `p` contains an object - `{id: Object, title: "asdgasdhc", body: "cc", starred: null, created_at: "2015-10-26T18:41:52.686Z"…}` - which is supposed to be okay.

Comment: so try to extend out of that push and the push the result to the array

Comment: have you tried `p.$save().then(function(response){ })` then on a separate line within the then block pushing the response into the scoped variable?

Comment: Maybe a digest issue. Your modification doesn't trigger a digest. Try to put your code in a [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) function.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
p.$save().then(function(response){ 
     $scope.posts.push(response.id) 
});
```

Comment: Damn, still nothing. It still doesn't add the new record to the list of existing records.

Answer (score 0):

Angular extend doesn't save the list/array.
It extends the old list/array with new item.